# The getter 'filePath' is not defined for the class Asset after upgrading flutter in multi_image_picker

Tags: flutter, dart

In my code, I am using `multi_image_picker` plugin for picking images from the gallery. After upgrading flutter version in my code

```
String fileName = await ChoosenAssets[i].filePath;//this the part gives an error
String fileName2 = fileName.split("/").last;
var asdsad['file']=await MultipartFile.fromFile(fileName,filename:fileName2,);
FormData formData = new FormData.fromMap(asdsad);
```

. Before this worked fine. And I downgraded flutter version the error disappeared. 
So How can I get `filePath` with upgraded flutter version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. In the [repo](https://github.com/Sh1d0w/multi_image_picker/issues) of the multi_image_picker package you can find [this issue](https://github.com/Sh1d0w/multi_image_picker/issues/337). In that issue the developers of the package mentioned that the `filePath` getter was only a experiment, but in the newest versions they removed it because it didnt work on all the operative systems nor devices. Also they mention you shouldn't need to get the `filePath` because:

1. You can do all the things you need only with the `Asset`.
2. The `filePath` in iOS is nowadays temporary, so even if you get it, in a few moments it will be useless.

This is a short summary, but if you need more details please go to the link I provided above.

Comment: Without `filePath` how can I create file `MultipartFile.fromFile`?

Comment: You can use [MultipartFile.fromBytes](https://pub.dev/documentation/dio/latest/dio/MultipartFile/MultipartFile.fromBytes.html), and get the bytes from the asset (The Asset class has a method for that)